# How to make a Flask API on GCP run on https instead of http

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, https, ssl-certificate

I have a flask API which is running on a google VM instance but currently it is running on http. So for instance, http://36.137.283.44:5000/get_values is the url for one endpoint where 36.137.283.44 is the external IP of the VM instance and 5000 is the port. I just want to the http to become https.

I've seen some answers which use load balancers and others which add ssl related code in the app.py file itself but neither seem to work.

Comment: Install an SSL certificate from comodo or cloudflare it'll change the status from http to https

Comment: @HassaanAli to do this would I need to add the ssl certificate code in my app.py file

Comment: Flask supports SSL certificates. This also means you want to serve traffic over port 443. Binding to ports below 1024 requires privilege. You do not want to run Flask with privilege. That is one of the reasons why load balancers, Nginx, etc. are used.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you please tell the steps to setup https for the google vm instance? There is no domain here, I just want to add https to the external ip address of my vm instance - every tutorial or ssl certificate asks for a domain name.

Comment: Google search. There are good tutorials on Flask with self-signed certificates published on the Internet. Example: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the SSL certificate to run flask on https.
Once you have the private key  and certificate pem files for the SSL.
Copy it to the folder where you are the running the python API. Say you copied over the `cert.pem` and `key.pem`, to the API code folder then change the API code for the following line to below.

```
application.run(host="0.0.0.0",
                port=5000,
                debug=True,
                ssl_context=("cert.pem", "key.pem"))
```

If you hit the IP after this you might get safety error as the certificate is issued for a certain domain name, try calling with the same.